# Slightly undercooked chickpeas

Tags: chickpeas

I have cooked some chickpeas and then frozen them. They taste as if they are slightly undercooked.
If I now defrost and cook them further, can I expect them to soften more?

Answer (score 3):

I see several references to freezing cooked chickpeas, and references to freezing soaked (but not yet cooked) chickpeas on the internets, so have no reason to believe that you can't do the same with par cooked chickpeas.  You should be able to cook to your liking after freezing.